# Merge multi-indexed with single-indexed data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. df1 is multi-indexed:

```
                value
first second    
a     x         0.471780
      y         0.774908
      z         0.563634
b     x         -0.353756
      y         0.368062
      z         -1.721840
```

and df2:

```
      value
first   
a     10
b     20
```

How can I merge the two data frames with only one of the multi-indexes, in this case the 'first' index? The desired output would be:

```
                value1      value2
first second    
a     x         0.471780    10
      y         0.774908    10
      z         0.563634    10
b     x         -0.353756   20
      y         0.368062    20
      z         -1.721840   20
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#reconstructing-the-level-labels):

```
firsts = df1.index.get_level_values('first')
df1['value2'] = df2.loc[firsts].values
```

Note: you are *almost* doing a [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#joining-on-index) here (except the df1 is MultiIndex)... so there may be a neater way to describe this...

.

In an example (similar to what you have):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'x', 0.123], ['a','x', 0.234],
                    ['a', 'y', 0.451], ['b', 'x', 0.453]],
                   columns=['first', 'second', 'value1']
                   ).set_index(['first', 'second'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 10],['b', 20]],
                   columns=['first', 'value']).set_index(['first'])

firsts = df1.index.get_level_values('first')
df1['value2'] = df2.loc[firsts].values

In [5]: df1
Out[5]: 
              value1  value2
first second                
a     x        0.123      10
      x        0.234      10
      y        0.451      10
b     x        0.453      20
```

Comment: you can *nearly* merge like this: `df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1.index.get_level_values('first'), right_on=df2.index.get_level_values('first'))`

Comment: This method works fine in the given exeample but I wonder what will happen when the single-indexes are different in some (e.g. more elements in one)

Comment: Starting from v.0.23, it's possible to use `left_on='name_of_index_level'`; IOW, @AndyHayden 's example simplifies to `df1.merge(df2, left_on='first', right_on='first')`.

Comment: @Axel I seem to be losing the other index level when following your advice.  But I am merging with `how="left"`, so to avoid this effect, I just store the original index and then assign it `df_merged.index = index`. Thanks to `how="left"`, the new and old indices will always have the same length.

Answer (score 19):

According to [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-a-single-index-to-a-multi-index), as of pandas 0.14, you can simply join single-index and multiindex dataframes. It will match on the common index name. The `how` argument works as expected with `'inner'` and `'outer'`, though interestingly it seems to be reversed for `'left'` and `'right'` (could this be a bug?).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'x', 0.471780], ['a','y', 0.774908], ['a', 'z', 0.563634],
                    ['b', 'x', -0.353756], ['b', 'y', 0.368062], ['b', 'z', -1.721840],
                    ['c', 'x', 1], ['c', 'y', 2], ['c', 'z', 3],
                   ],
                   columns=['first', 'second', 'value1']
                   ).set_index(['first', 'second'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 10], ['b', 20]],
                   columns=['first', 'value2']).set_index(['first'])

print(df1.join(df2, how='inner'))
                value1  value2
first second                  
a     x       0.471780      10
      y       0.774908      10
      z       0.563634      10
b     x      -0.353756      20
      y       0.368062      20
      z      -1.721840      20
```

Answer (score 3):

As the `.ix` syntax is a powerful shortcut to reindexing, but in this case you are actually not doing any combined rows/column reindexing, this can be done a bit more elegantly (for my humble taste buds) with just using reindexing:

Preparation from hayden:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'x', 0.123], ['a','x', 0.234],
                    ['a', 'y', 0.451], ['b', 'x', 0.453]],
                   columns=['first', 'second', 'value1']
                   ).set_index(['first', 'second'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 10],['b', 20]],
                   columns=['first', 'value']).set_index(['first'])
```

Then this looks like this in iPython:

```
In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
              value1
first second        
a     x        0.123
      x        0.234
      y        0.451
b     x        0.453

In [5]: df2
Out[5]: 
       value
first       
a         10
b         20

In [7]: df2.reindex(df1.index, level=0)
Out[7]: 
              value
first second       
a     x          10
      x          10
      y          10
b     x          20

In [8]: df1['value2'] = df2.reindex(df1.index, level=0)

In [9]: df1
Out[9]: 
              value1  value2
first second                
a     x        0.123      10
      x        0.234      10
      y        0.451      10
b     x        0.453      20
```

The mnemotechnic for what level you have to use in the reindex method:
It states for the level that you already covered in the bigger index.
So, in this case df2 already had level 0 covered of the df1.index.