# How to combine dates and hours column into one index column in a pandas series?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, series, multi-index

I have a pandas series which looks as follows:

```
df.head()
Country  Day         Hour
DE       2013-01-01  1       36504
                     2       35142
                     3       33723
                     4       32375
                     5       31876
dtype: float64
```

with

```
'Country', 'Day', 'Hour'
```

as the index columns (MultiIndex) and 'Day' in DateTime format. The actual values (load) are in the unlabelled column.

I now would like to combine the 'Day' and 'Hour' columns into one 'Date' index column. I did a lot of searching and so far I have only seen solutions that are based on pd.read_csv and pd.read_table. However, as this is a series (not a dataframe / csv / excel), these solutions do not seem to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them (if you first multiply the hours by the number of nanoseconds), but you have to drop down to numpy to do the calculation*:

```
In [11]: dr = pd.date_range('2014', periods=5)

In [12]: hours = pd.Index(np.arange(5))

In [13]: pd.DatetimeIndex(dr.values + hours.values * pd.offsets.Hour(1).nanos)
Out[13]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2014-01-05 04:00:00]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

*Note: each level in a MultiIndex is an Index, but this would work just the same with a Series or np.array.*

*Apparently Index overrides the `+` operator to make it append...

Access the levels of a MultiIndex using `get_level_values`, see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14149319/1240268).

Answer (score 2):

```
df["Day"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["Hour"])
```

should work.